# Powershell : How to format the output of get-netadapter command to a single list/line with a delimiter

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get the output of get-netadapter from powershell, from specific fields in the form of list/dict/json.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden | Format-List -Property Name,AdminStatus,DriverFileName


Name           : Ethernet0
AdminStatus    : Up
DriverFileName : e1i63x64.sys

Name           : Ethernet (Kernel Debugger)
AdminStatus    : Down
DriverFileName : kdnic.sys

Name           : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
AdminStatus    : Down
DriverFileName :

Name           : Microsoft IP-HTTPS Platform Interface
AdminStatus    : Down
DriverFileName :

Name           : 6to4 Adapter
AdminStatus    : Down
DriverFileName :
```

Required output format in the form of a list/dict/json.

**Example format :**

```
(Name: Ethernet0, AdminStatus: Up, DriverFileName : e1i63x64.sys;
 Name: Ethernet (Kernel Debugger), AdminStatus: Down, DriverFileName: kdnic.sys)
```

So the individual adapters are separated by ';' and the individual objects of a single adapter is separated by ','.

I tried using 'join' operator but that doesn't seem to work.
ConvertTo-Json doesn't seem work if I use format-list/format-table

Comment: If you want to convert your output objects to JSON using the cmdlet `ConvertTo-JSON` you cannot use format cmdlets before. Actually you should not use format cmdlets at all when you want to do further steps with your objects/data.  ;-)  If you want to limit the ouput to specific properties you should use a `Select-Object` instead of `Format-List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert to json, directly do the command:

```
Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden | 
    Select-Object -Property Name,AdminStatus,DriverFileName |
    ConvertTo-Json
```

result:

```
[
    {
        "Name":  "Connexion au réseau local* 7",
        "AdminStatus":  1,
        "DriverFileName":  "ndiswan.sys"
    },
    {
        "Name":  "Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface",
        "AdminStatus":  2,
        "DriverFileName":  null
    },
    {
        "Name":  "Ethernet0",
        "AdminStatus":  1,
        "DriverFileName":  "e1i65x64.sys"
    },
    {
        "Name":  "Connexion au réseau local* 3",
        "AdminStatus":  1,
        "DriverFileName":  "rasl2tp.sys"
    },
    {
        "Name":  "6to4 Adapter",
        "AdminStatus":  2,
        "DriverFileName":  null
    }
]
```